# Cannot use cordova facebook plugin on visual studio 2015

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am creating a Visual Studio 2015 RC Tools for Apache Cordova project and I'm trying to install facebook plugin from https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin . 
It's installed successfully but when building the app I'm getting this:

```
1>  ------ Adding plugin: com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@0.11.0
1>  Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@0.11.0"
1>  Fetching plugin "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@0.11.0" via plugin registry
1>  Copying plugin "C:\Users\admin\.plugman\cache\com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect\0.11.0\package" => "C:\VS Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\plugins\com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect"
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Build fails I cannot find the reason why.

Comment: There's NO other build info or errors? What's in your errors list window?

Comment: i am also facing similar issues. mine in error says Severity Code Description Project File Line
`Error  404 Not Found: com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin work c:\users\deep.mehta\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects1\work\work\MDAVSCLI 1`

Comment: Based on your original post i don't think the build failed because of the plugin. Can you include more info from the build output?

Answer (score 0):

The plugins has symlinks that don't seem to work on windows. Is this also failing when you try it on a Mac ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is often better to install plugins from command line rather than using visual studio.

Eg. Cordova plugin add phonegap-facebook-plugin